# if-else block in lua script

Tags: if-statement, lua

I'm trying to create an if-else statement in Lua script. But I can't really get it to work :( This is what I have.

First I have a randomizer that can choose between some plans

```
local phones_priceplan = {
    { priceplan = 'Fast'},
    { priceplan = 'Mini'},
    { priceplan = 'kort'},
}
local rnd_priceplan     =   math.random(1, #phones_priceplan)
local priceplan         =   phones_priceplan[rnd_priceplan]['priceplan']
```

Then if the **priceplan** is equal to **'Fast'** I want to run another randomizer

```
if priceplan == "Fastpris"
    local fastpris_plan = {
        {   price = '145',  gb = '0.5', },
        {   price = '195',  gb = '2',   },
        {   price = '245',  gb = '6',   },

    }
    local rnd_phone_surf_plan       =   math.random(1, #fastpris_plan)
    local surf_price            =   fastpris_plan[rnd_phone_surf_plan]['surf_price']
end
```

But it is with the if statement that it seems so crash. Any ideas on what could possible be wrong :)?

Comment: You should have got this error message: `'then' expected near 'local'`, which is quite clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua, the syntax of an `if` statement is as follows:

```
if cond then
    statement
elseif cond then
    statement
else
    if cond then
        statement
    else
        statement
    end
end
```

You're missing the `then` clause.

Comment: I went to the bathroom and though. I maybe forgot the then clause...
and hurry back to remove my question :) But yes sir it worked right away.
thank you so much.